# Containable behaviour cakephp with HABTM

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I am tryning to fetch data using containable behaviour of cakephp.

How my Models are associated:

```
 A => HABTM <= B
 B => HABTM < C
```

What i need as result array structure:

```
array(
        [A] => array(),
        [B] => array(
            [C] => array()
        )
 )
```

I have reached up to fetch array of:

```
 array(
        [A] => array(),
        [B] => array()
 )
```

I have tried for required array result but does not get solution for it.

What query I am trying:

```
 $this->A->Behaviors->load('Containable');
    $contain = array('contain'=>array(
                'B' => array(
                    'C'
                )
          )
    );

While trying the query , i am getting output as follows:

array(
        [A] => array(),
        [B] => array(
            [C] => array()
        )
 )
```

but the model 'C' data is empty

Does anyone know how to do it??

Answer (score -1):

Well you never defined how your tables are connected to each other, at least C => B.

e.g.

```
$this->A->Behaviors->load('Containable');
$contain = array('contain'=>array(
            'B' => array(
                'C' => array(
                    'conditions' => array('B.name' => 'C.name'),
                )
            )
      )
);
```

This would retrieve A, B and C table where B.name == C.name.

Please a take a brief look [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#containing-deeper-associations).

Comment: But there  is no column common in B and C model. They are associated with HABTM.